# What does it mean when my application can't run on debug mode, but the exe files can run perfectly fine?

Tags: c++, mfc

What does it mean when my application can't run on debug mode, but the exe files can run perfectly fine?

I'm concerned, because I can't run my application on Debug mode in visual studio, but
on release configuration, it works fine.

Also the EXEs work fine.

Why doesn't it run on debug mode?

Comment: Do you get an error message from Visual Studio when you try to run the program?

Comment: it can mean many things, hard to tell when you give us literally zero code or error information.

Comment: What does "Can't run" mean ? Does it crash ? Doesn't it even start ? Is there an error message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are lucky. The reverse problem is very difficult to troubleshoot. But since your problem occurs in Debug mode, you can use the debugger to debug it. That's what it's for.